# Do IMS journals count as open access?

Tags: open-access

I'm considering submitting a paper to Annals of Applied Statistics, published by the Institute of Mathematical Statistics (IMS).

According to [IMS Journals on arXiv](http://imstat.org/publications/arxiv.html):

> Note that the IMS posts all accepted IMS journal articles on arXiv at publication.

However, the paper entries on the journal page do not link directly to the arXiv paper. Also, for at least [the following publication](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1380804802), there is no corresponding entry on arXiv. I'm not sure what to conclude from that.

So, I was just wondering if this approach counts as open access. Also, the Wikipedia entry, [Comparison of statistics journals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_statistics_journals) lists Annals of Applied Statistics and other IMS journals as not open access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive place to check is the IMS's [Copyright Transfer Agreement](http://imstat.org/publications/copyrights/copyrightTA.pdf), which conclusively says:

> However, the author(s) reserve the following:
>
> 1. All proprietary rights other than copyright, such as patent rights.
> 2. The rights to use all or part of this work (with appropriate reference to the journal and article) in future works of
>      their own, such as lectures, press releases, reviews, textbooks, or reprint books.
> 3. The right to **place the final version of this article** (exactly as published in the journal) **on their own homepage or in
>      a public digital repository**, provided there is a link to the official journal site.
> 4. The right to provide a copy of the final peer‐reviewed manuscript to the NIH upon acceptance for publication, for
>      public archiving in PubMed Central as soon as possible but no later than 12 months after publication.

So the IMS follows the **[green open access model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access)** (which is confirmed by [Sherpa/ROMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/search.php?issn=1932-6157)).

Comment: Thanks, F'x, that's helpful. So, does that mean Wikipedia is wrong? Also, did you mean "definitive" rather than "definite"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes, but it is possible that Wikipedia is referring to “gold” open access…